# Solid sphere not visible on the screen

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I'm trying to combine lighting with 3D graphics.There's sphere that is on depth 100, and it has 100 as radius.I use translatef to make it be far from the eye position.
But nothing is displayed on the screen:

```
#import <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#import <GLUT/GLUT.h>

GLfloat width=500, height=500;
GLfloat angle=0.0;

void makeRound (GLfloat* angle)
{
    if(*angle>360.0)
    {
        *angle-=360.0;
    }
    else if(*angle<0.0)
    {
        *angle+=360.0;
    }
}

void init(void)
{
    GLfloat mat_specular[]   = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    GLfloat mat_diffuse[]    = { 0.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    GLfloat mat_shininess[]  = { 50.0 };
    GLfloat light_position[] = { 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat white_light[]    = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat lmodel_ambient[] = { 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 1.0 };

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 1, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, 1, 1, 1000);

    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel (GL_SMOOTH);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, white_light);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR,white_light);
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT,lmodel_ambient);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 100);
    glutSolidSphere (100.0, 80, 64);
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}


void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case '+':
            angle+=5.0;
            makeRound(&angle);
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case '-':
            angle-=5.0;
            makeRound(&angle);
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize (width, height);
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    init ();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is what I see with :

```
glTranslatef(0,0,-200);
```

[image]

Comment: If you draw a sphere with radius 100 at the position (0, 0, 100), then the camera is within the sphere and you won't see anything. Furthermore, if you suspect lighting to be wrong, try setting the clear color to a non black color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a result of your translate you are actually positioned on the edge of the sphere.  That means the polys actually go though "you".  You won't see anything as a result of your near clip plane and thanks to back-face culling you can't see the tris on the other side of the sphere.

Set either:

```
glCullFace( GL_FRONT );
```

Or set the transform to push the sphere further away:

```
glTranslatef(0, 0, -200);
```

Comment: I tried both ways, both not working.Only with -200 it seems to draw something on the screen, but it's a big sphere and it seems like the eye is inside it.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: Try pushing the camera even further away ... try -1000 and see what happens ...

Comment: This case I see the sphere correctly.But I still don't understand why.

Comment: @ramyalzuhouri: Because you are too close to it.  For an analogy if you close one eye (remember you are not doing stereographic rendering) and hold a ball right in front of your ye you can't see any definition in the sphere.  Now move it further away and pay attention to how far you need to move it before you can see the ball properly (we won't get into focus as thats a whole other subject).  Now remember that you have set your field of view to 45 degrees and your eye's field of view is much much larger.

Comment: But I'm looking to (0,0,100) from (0,0,0), the translatef should have a positive value, otherwise the sphere would be behind the eye.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: There must be some form of z value negation happening in one of the matrices generated by glut.  I, personally, don't ever use glut.  I prefer to use my own matrix/vector classes so i know exactly whats going on underneath.

Comment: I didn't notice that I was reloading the identity to the gluLookAt made in the init method had no effect.